# Confusion in notation of representation of Bastiani derivative

Tags: vector-bundles, schwartz-distributions, derivations

In the paper "[Properties of field functionals and characterization of local functionals](https://hal.science/hal-01654120/document)" at page 5 the Authors give the following definitions

> Definition II.2. Let $U$ be an open subset of a Hausdorff locally convex space $E$ and let $f$ be a nap from $U$ to a Hausdorff locally convex space $F$. Then $f$ is said to have a derivative at $x \in U$ in the lirection of $v \in E$ if the following limit exists: ${ }^{.3}$
> $$
> D f_x(v):=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+t v)-f(x)}{t} .
> $$
>
> Definition II.3. Let $U$ be an open subset of a Hausdorff locally convex space E and let fe a map from $U$ to a Hausdorff locally convex space $F$. Then $f$ is Bastiani differentiable on $U$ [denoted by $\left.f \in C^1(U)\right]$ iff has a Gâteaux differential at every $x \in U$ and the map $D f: U \times E \rightarrow F$ defined by $D f(x, v)=D f_x(v)$ is continuous on $U \times E$.

At page  24 they state the following

> Lemma VI.2. Let $U$ be an open subset of $C^{\infty}(M)$ and $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be Bastiani smooth. For every $\varphi$ such that the distribution $D F_{\varphi} \in \mathcal{E}^{\prime}(M)$ has an empty wave front set, there exists a unique function $\nabla F_{\varphi} \in \mathcal{D}(M)$ such that
> $$
> D F_{\varphi}[h]=\int_M \nabla F_{\varphi}(x) h(x) d x
> $$

Here $\mathcal{D}(M)$ is the space of test function on $M$ and $\mathcal{E}^{\prime}(M)$
is the dual of the space of section $\Gamma (E)$

Since $h(x)$ is a section in Lemma VI.2,  how can we produce a  number by multiplying  it by a function and then intergrate it ?

Am I missing something?

Comment: The erratic punctuation in your last paragraph makes it really difficult to understand what your question is. :(

Comment: @ 
Igor Khavkine I edited my question.

Comment: I may still be misunderstanding your question, but any inclusion $\mathcal{D}(M) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{E}'(M)$ requires a distinguished volume form. If that's not made clear in the article, they must have left it implicit or forgot about it.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine in $D F_{\varphi}[h]=\int_M \nabla F_{\varphi}(x) h(x) d x$ , $D F_{\varphi}[h]$ is a number , $h(x)$ is a section  of a vector bundle and $\nabla F_{\varphi}(x)$ is a function  . We need that $\nabla F_{\varphi}(x)$  be a section of the dual bundle in order that the expression make sense

Comment: Distinguished volume form. $\uparrow$